# Why the input of tensorflow SimpleRNNCell is 3D?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am testing tensorflow `tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell`. I find it was so strange. I think a RNN cell is a unit to receive previous state `a^{<t-1>}` and the current data input `x^{<t>}`. It will output a new state `a^{<t>}` and current predict `\hat{y}^{<t>}`.

[image]

So a `SimpleRNNCell` input should be a 2d if batch_size is set. I think the input should be `[batch_size,feature_size]`. However it will raise error if the input is 2D. And previous states also need 3D.

The right code is as follows:

```
batch_data = tf.ones((batch_size, time_steps, label_num))    
simple_rnn_cell = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell(units)
initial_state = tf.zeros((batch_size, time_steps, units))
output, rnn_cell_state = simple_rnn_cell(batch_data, initial_state)
```

However, I think following code was right. But I am wrong

```
batch_data = tf.ones((batch_size, label_num))    
simple_rnn_cell = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell(units)
initial_state = tf.zeros((batch_size, units))
output, rnn_cell_state = simple_rnn_cell(batch_data, initial_state)
```

So my question is why the input of `SimpleRNNCell` is 3D?

Answer (score 1):

A 3rd dimension is a number of features and it is used for multivariate time series. In your case, for the number of features is used 1. For example, you can think that tensor [1,2,3] is 1D, [[1,2,3]] is 2D with shape (1,3), [[[1,2,3]]] is 3D with shape (1,1,3) and so on.

So, if we take one input sample, one variate time series would be [[1,2,3]] but two variate time series can look like [[1,2,3], [7,8,9]].

Answer (score 0):

The input of the RNN (or LSTM) should have a shape of [batch_size, timesteps, nbr_features]

Comment: I know it. But here what I am asking is SimpleRNNCell which is a cell of a RNN